# how to avoid repeating similiar onclick events in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have list items with very similar `onClick` functionality on each and I'm not sure how to avoid repeating myself. I believe I could somehow use a map but I'm struggling to think of the solution for it. Any suggestions, please?

```
          <li
            onClick={() => {
              setSortTitle("Release Date");
              setIsActive(false);
              dispatch(sortByReleaseDate(searchedMovies));
            }}
          >
            <a href="#">Release Date</a>
          </li>
          <li
            onClick={() => {
              setSortTitle("Rating");
              setIsActive(false);
              dispatch(sortByRating(searchedMovies));
            }}
          >
            <a href="#">Rating</a>
          </li>
          <li
            onClick={() => {
              setSortTitle("Run Time");
              setIsActive(false);
              dispatch(sortByRuntime(searchedMovies));
            }}
          >
            <a href="#">Run Time</a>
          </li>
          <li
            onClick={() => {
              setSortTitle("Title");
              setIsActive(false);
              dispatch(sortByTitle(searchedMovies));
            }}
          >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array of links that contains the information needed to create a link (and is also easy to add to!). Then utilising `map()` you can render each link and utilise a generic `linkClicked` function to then action the dispatch with the relevant search function.

```
const links = [
    { label: 'Release Date', sortFn: sortByReleaseDate },
    { label: 'Rating', sortFn: sortByRating },
    { label: 'Run Time', sortFn: sortByRuntime },
    { label: 'Title', sortFn: sortByTitle }
]

const linkClicked = (link) => {
    setSortTitle(link.label);
    setIsActive(false);
    dispatch(link.sortFn(searchedMovies));
}

return links.map(link => (
    <li onClick={() => linkClicked(link)}>
        <a href="#">{link.label}</a>
    </li>
))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a `titles` array along with a single `onItemClick(title)` event handler and also a more generic `sortBy` action creator where you can take title as another argument or even combine `{title,searchMovies}` into single object (upto you):-

```
const titles = ["Release Date","Rating","Run Time"]

const onItemClick=(title) => {
          setSortTitle(title);
          setIsActive(false);
          dispatch(sortBy(title,searchedMovies));
        }

{titles.map(title=>
 (<li onClick={() => onItemClick(title)}>
  <a href="#">{title}</a>
</li>)
)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map method:

```
const onListItemClick = (title) => {
    setSortTitle(title);
    setIsActive(false);
    dispatch(sortByReleaseDate(searchedMovies)); 
} 

const LI = () => LiObject.map((item) => (
  <li
    onClick={e => onListItemClick(item.title, e)}
  >
    <a href="#">{item.label}</a>
  </li>
));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the function with a input param

```
        const onListItemClick=(title) => {
          setSortTitle(title);
          setIsActive(false);
          dispatch(sortByReleaseDate(searchedMovies));
        }
```

and invoke it using bind in the onClick handler

```
  <li
    onClick={onListItemClick.bind(this, "Release Date")}
  >
    <a href="#">Release Date</a>
  </li>
```

Another suggestion would be to grab the title from the synthetic event.

E.g.

```
       const onListItemClick=(e) => {
          const title=e.target.innerHTML; 
          console.log(title);
          setSortTitle(title);
          setIsActive(false);
          dispatch(sortByReleaseDate(searchedMovies));
        }
```

html

```
      <li
        onClick={onListItemClick}
      >
        <a href="#">Release Date</a>
      </li>
      <li
        onClick={onListItemClick}
      >
        <a href="#">Rating</a>
      </li>
      <li
        onClick={onListItemClick}
      >
        <a href="#">Run Time</a>
      </li>
```